# How to use extra space after tabs in tabsheet

Tags: vaadin

i am new to vaadin , i created tabsheet with two tabs one with graphs and another with some info, my problem was how to add components(combobox, labels) at right corner(same row) of the tabs.

```
final TabSheet tabSheet = new TabSheet();
    tabSheet.setSizeFull();
    tabSheet.addTab(rightAndLowerPanels, "Graphs");
    tabSheet.addTab(new Label("<b>Haiiiiiiiiiiiii</b>", ContentMode.HTML), "Message");
```

Ex;
tab1|tab2          
**I want to add here**
i am not able to post image for this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: As my knowledge of vaadin goes, I don't think that is possible

Comment: Thanku patton any other way that i can do that , i need tabsheet and components side by side.

Answer (score 1):

While the component itself doesn't support this, it is possible to accomplish this with setting the components absolute position with css so it hovers over the tabsheet in the correct position.

The div(layout) that contains the tabseet and the hovering component should be set `position: relative;` so that the absolute position is set from the corner of the component not the browser and then set the combobox's position to something like this: `position:absolute; right: 3px; top: 3px;`.

You can even use Vaadin's AbsoluteLayout or CssLayout if you want to add some checks for determining the components position.

```
AbsoluteLayout al = new AbsoluteLayout();
al.addStyleName("tab-sheet-layout"); // position: relative;
al.addComponent(new TabSheet(new Label("1"),new Label("2")));
al.addComponent(new ComboBox(), "right: 5px; top: 5px;");
```

or with CssLayout:

```
public static class TabSheetLayout extends CssLayout {
    public TabSheetLayout() {
        addStyleName("tab-sheet-layout"); // position: relative;
        addComponent(new TabSheet(new Label("1"),new Label("2")));
        addComponent(new ComboBox());
    }

    @Override
    protected String getCss(Component c) {
        if (c instanceof ComboBox) { // do some check here
            return "position:absolute; right: 3px; top: 3px;";
        }
        return null;
    }  
}
```

You should note however that if you resize the screen small enough, the combobox will be hovering over the tabs, so you need to stop this by fixing the layout width or by some other method.